# What's the age in which people are allowed to engage in cybersex in Germany?

Tags: germany, age

As far as I understand, Germany has an age of consent of 14 or 16 depending on the context but in addition a law. On the other hand [§ 184](https://dejure.org/gesetze/StGB/184.html) sets up a ban for "Verbreitung pornographischer Schriften".

> Translation via [Gesetze im Internet](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_stgb/englisch_stgb.html#p1644)
>
> §184 Distribution of pornography
>
> (1) Whosoever with regard to pornographic written materials (section
>   11(3))
>
> 1. offers, gives or makes them accessible to a person under eighteen years of age;

Does cybersex, especially when it's text-based, fall under that statute and is therefore outlawed?

Comment: For those of us who don’t speak German, would you summarise what the law says in English. Also, it is poor form on se to put a major component of a question in a link in case of link rot - we need a complete question here.

Comment: *especially when it's text-based* – Note that “written materials” is a translation of *Schriften,* which in turn is defined (in §11 (3)) to contain all sorts of materials, in particular pictures and videos. I don’t consider *written materials* a good translation here. With other words, text-based material has no special status in this law, even if it may appear so at first glance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Does cybersex count as *pornography?*

The law does not define *pornography,* so this is up to an interpretation of the courts. However, it appears to be common consent that a depersonalisation of the subjects is an essential aspect. For example, [this verdict](http://www.gerichtsentscheidungen.berlin-brandenburg.de/jportal/portal/t/2wf4/bs/10/page/sammlung.psml?pid=Dokumentanzeige&showdoccase=1&js_peid=Trefferliste&documentnumber=1&numberofresults=1&fromdoctodoc=yes&doc.id=KORE228652008%3Ajuris-r02&doc.part=L) notes (translations and emphasis mine):

> Pornographie liegt nach der Rechtsprechung des Bundesgerichtshofs und der Oberlandesgerichte vor, wenn eine Darstellung **unter Ausklammerung aller sonstigen menschlichen Bezüge** sexuelle Vorgänge […] in den Vordergrund rückt […] (vgl. BGHSt 37, 55 (60); 32, 40 (44 ff); OLG Karlsruhe NJW 1974, 2015 (2016); OLG Düsseldorf NJW 1974, 1474 (1475); ebenso BVerwG NJW 2002, 2966 (2969)).
>
> […]
>
> Hinzukommen muss deshalb als weiteres Kriterium die sog. „**Apersonalität des Geschlechtspartners**“ (vgl. Erdemir, MMR 2003, 628 (631)). Die Darstellung muss mit anderen Worten durch eine Verabsolutierung sexuellen Lustgewinns unter gleichzeitiger **Entmenschlichung der Sexualität** geprägt sein. Pornographie ist danach anzunehmen, **wenn der Mensch im Rahmen der Darstellung zum bloßen, auswechselbaren Objekt** sexueller Begierde degradiert wird (vgl. S/S/Lenckner/Perron/Eisele, StGB 27. Aufl., § 184 Rdn. 4; MK-Hörnle a.a.O., § 184 Rdn. 15; jeweils m. w. Nachw.). […]

---

> According to the Federal Court’s and the state courts’ jurisdiction, a depiction is pornography if it emphasises sexual procedures **disregarding all human aspects** [references]
>
> […]
>
> Therefore, a necessary further criterion is the so-called “**depersonalisation of the sexual partner**” [reference].
>   With other words, the depiction must be dominated by a absolutisation of sexual pleasure and a simultaneous **dehumanisation of sexuality**.
>   Therefore pornography has to be asserted if **a depiction reduces human beings to mere replaceable objects** of sexual desire [references].

(Also see [the German Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pornografie#Definition) for another summary and further references on the subject.)

Now, cybersex usually, if not inherently, is a personal procedure, as opposed to a depersonalised one. Therefore I would not consider it to fall under the quoted definition of *pornography.*

#### What other laws *do* regulate cybersex?

The law governing the age of consent is [§ 176 StGB](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/stgb/__176.html) ([translation](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_stgb/englisch_stgb.html#p1538)), which includes:

> (4) Mit Freiheitsstrafe […] wird bestraft, wer […] auf ein Kind mittels Schriften (§ 11 Absatz 3) oder mittels Informations- oder Kommunikationstechnologie einwirkt, um […] das Kind zu sexuellen Handlungen zu bringen, die es […] vor dem Täter […] vornehmen […] soll, […]

---

> (4) Whosoever […] influences a child with written materials (section 11(3)) or with information or communication technology to induce him to engage in sexual activity […] in the presence of the offender […] shall be liable to imprisonment […].
>
> *Translation adapted from [this one](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_stgb/englisch_stgb.html#p1538) to reflect [recent changes](http://lexetius.com/StGB/176,2) to the law.

Note that *Kind (child)* was established as *Person unter vierzehn Jahren (a person under fourteen years of age)* before.

I would interpret this to capture cybersex. The only thing about this that may be debatable is whether the sexual activity during cybersex happens *in the presence* of the offender (i.e., the other person).

Comment: As far as I understand the term "Kind (child)" in the law is about human with age 14 or below, so if I understand you right cybersex between 14 and 18 is legal in Germany?

Comment: @Timothy: see my edit.

Comment: Sex with a 14 year old is legal if the partner is of the same age. If the partner is older, it becomes a bit more complicated.